# Javascript Split difference

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Javascript**

```
var sitename="Welcome to JavaScript Kit"
var words=sitename.split(" ") //split using blank space as delimiter
for (var i=0; i<words.length; i++)
alert(words[i]) 
//4 alerts: "Welcome", "to", "JavaScript", and "Kit"
```

And

```
var sitename="Welcome to JavaScript Kit"
var words=sitename.split("") //split using blank space as delimiter
for (var i=0; i<words.length; i++)
alert(words[i]) 
//6 alerts: "W", "e", "l", "c","o","m"
```

What is the difference between

```
var words=sitename.split(" ");
```

And

```
var words=sitename.split("");
```

Here, what is the difference between two splits.

Comment: The difference is that when you split on spaces, each word becomes an array element.  And when you do a split on `""`, each character becomes an array element.

Comment: It probably is.  Using your JS console, try `("Welcome to JavaScript Kit").split("");` and inspect the output.

Comment: Did you by any chance check the `"Prevent this page from displaying additional messages"` on the sixth alert? (i.e. if you are using Chrome)

Answer (score 1):

```
var sitename="Welcome to JavaScript Kit"
var words=sitename.split("") //split using blank space as delimiter
for (var i=0; i<words.length; i++)
alert(words[i]) 
//6 alerts: "W", "e", "l", "c","o","m"
```

It wont stop on just m it will have many more alerts after that.

every word will be alerted till "K" "I" "T" http://jsfiddle.net/zwJJN/

```
var words=sitename.split("") //split using blank space as delimiter    

var words=sitename.split(" ") //split using white space space as delimiter
```

**When we use split the whole string is searched for the delimiter given and is splitted on the basis of that**

`var words=sitename.split("")`// every character is splitted.

```
var words=sitename.split(" ")// every words is splitted having white space before it.
```

Comment: what is difference between blankspace and white space? sorry to be dumb.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var words=sitename.split(" ");
```

This code is split by the blank space

```
    var words=sitename.split("");
```

But here you didnt given anything so it will be split the char's

Comment: Then, why is sitename.split(); returning complete string instead of splitting?

Answer (score 0):

```
var words=sitename.split(" ");
```

This one split the words using the `space`  **Welcometo**

```
var words=sitename.split("");
```

This one split the words using the character. i.e. Separate each charater, including white-space

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 0):

```
var words=sitename.split(" ");
```

this will split around space character

```
var words=sitename.split("");
```

this will split around each character

I ran the script and in my browser it is working fine, i get all alerts till the end 't'. may be your browser is not allowing the webpage to generate any more dialogs

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your browser is preventing the alerts from spamming

Don't use `alert` inspect the `.slice` result. Use something like `console.log` to get a better look

```
console.log("Welcome to JavaScript Kit".split(""));
// ["W", "e", "l", "c", "o", "m", "e", " ", "t", "o", " ", "J", "a", "v", "a", "S", "c", "r", "i", "p", "t", " ", "K", "i", "t"]
```

And

```
console.log("Welcome to JavaScript Kit".split(" "));
// ["Welcome", "to", "JavaScript", "Kit"]
```